# HTTPS Redirect in puma only working for the base URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, puma-dev

My puma server redirects from http -> https (in development) but only with one URL: `localhost:3000`. As soon as I add anything to the end (i.e. `localhost:3000/index`) it no longer redirects (and the page errors out).

Is there a config option I'm missing (or need to comment out)? I currently have:
 `ssl_bind 'localhost', '3000' { ... }` in config/puma.rb and
`force_ssl = true` in config/environments/development.rb.

Answer (score 4):

`force_ssl` is supposed to redirect all requests that come to http port to https, it cannot do anything when you're trying to connect via http to a https port.

http and https should be bound to different ports (`bind` and `ssl_bind` options). It is customary to have http development server at port 3000, so bind ssl at some other port (for example - 8443, standard for https is 443, but it's privileged)

Also for development specify ssl_options for redirecting:

```rb
config.ssl_options = {  redirect: { status: 307, port: 8443 } }
```

Comment: What if we want to use same port and forcefully redirect from http to https?

Comment: @Aashish port can be either http or https, not both at the same time